# HTML-assigned 'id' Missing in DOM

Tags: html, dom, moodle

Within the Moodle (v. 3.5.7) Atto editor (using both Chrome and Firefox) I've been trying to assign an ID to a particular row class, "span9". My ultimate objective is to assign this a unique ID and reference this element via jquery so as to append another element within it.

The ISSUE is that once I add an ID (id="checklist01") and click save, the ID simply does not appear in the DOM, and seems to not exist. When I re-enter the atto editor however, voila, there it is just sitting there. So it's NOT being removed completely... just not expressed somehow?

I have 2 screenshots linked below showing (1) the editor view, with the element and assigned ID highlighted, and (2) a screenshot of the DOM once the changes have been saved, with that same area highlighted, without the assigned ID.

[Screenshots of ID Missing from DOM](https://photos.app.goo.gl/k8DfUF8og2yzrRCm7)

Bootstrap ver. 4

So far I've tried switching the placement of the id in the atto editor (class coming first vs second after ); tried to add a "span" in front of the id (for some reason, I was desperate); and really just searched all over for someone who has encountered something similar.

I'm not sure how much help the html will provide, but here it is:

```
<div class="row-fluid colored">
  <div class="iconbox span3">
    h4>Your Completion Status (%)</h4>
  </div>

  <div id="checklist01" class="span9">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hey,
Can you please share which activity you used in your screenshot, this will help me to check more precisely for your issue.

Comment: Absolutely. It's actually the "checklist" activity. The content I'm adding the ID to is located in the activity 'summary'. If I can get you more specifics please let me know. If it helps, I am also using the Lambda theme at the site-level, and "Tiles" for the course layout. Thanks so much for helping out!

Comment: As an update, I was able to work around this by assigning a second unique class to the element, and then referring to that with the JQuery. It is STILL baffling why the ID won't work, so while it is no as urgent, I still think this is worthwhile looking into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason for the removal of id attributes.

id attributes are removed because "Checklist" activity used safe HTML function of Moodle. If you want to access id attributes of description HTML follow below steps.

1. Go to mod\checklist\locallib.php file.
2. Then search formatted_intro() function (which is around line number 880).
3. In that function they used Moodle's format_text() function to return description text.
4. In that function, they have used 3 parameters.

   - string $text The text to be formatted.
   - int $format Identifier of the text format to be used
   - object/array $options text formatting options

Replace

```
$opts = array('trusted' => $CFG->enabletrusttext);
```

to

```
$opts = array('trusted' => $CFG->enabletrusttext,'allowid'=>true);
```

Then save your file and check. By following the above steps you can use id attributes.